# Can't scan QR code for WhatsApp web due to camera inverted or tilted on Galaxy Y Duos

Tags: camera, whatsapp-messenger, qr-code

First of all, I already read the other posts about problems reading the QR Code, and my problem is different.

1. I have a Galaxy Y Duos, so my screen is bigger than 4 inches.
2. I do get the "Ok, got it" message, and can successfully press it.
3. I'm using Google Chrome.
4. My WhatsApp is up to date (re-installed it several times trying to solve the problem)

What is happening is that the display for the camera inside WhatsApp is inverted (or tilted sideways). When I move the phone up and down, the image goes left and right, and vice-versa. It is like that both for taking pictures to send someone, and for scanning the QR code.

So, since the QR code depends on orientation of the image, the app cannot read the inverted image. I tried inverting the PC screen itself to correct the issue, but it seems that there's no screen orientation that gives the proper reading of the code. Plus it's really annoying trying to focus the code, as the image doesn't behave as expected.

The camera works fine outside WhatsApp and other QR readers (I have QR Droid installed) works perfectly.

The problem is also independent of screen auto-rotation, I turned it on and off, and tried to manually rotate the screen, but the camera image stays tilted.

Answer (score 3):

I had the very same issue with my Galaxy Y Duos. Rotating the phone or laptop screen through screen preferences didn't help me. Finally the solution was to use '[Flip This](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flip-this/donljlliiecjcagcenoeohjmabfegkph?hl=en)' chrome extension and rotate the QR code by 90 degrees. The WhatsApp logo at the center of the QR code would not change its orientation on the camera (as it is a different image) but the QR code would be rotated and your phone would be able to scan it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the Deluminate plug-in enabled on chrome. It worked perfect once i disabled the extension!

Comment: I was using Dark Reader - similar to Deluminate - and could not log in for the same reason: the colours were inverted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, turned out that the camera lens was dirty and didn't allow the camera to focus properly. Quick clean of the lens and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

My old Samsung phone does the same:

When I move the cellphone up and down, the image goes left and right, and vice-versa. This happens when taking pictures, and for scanning the QR code.

But you can still scan the QR code for WhatsApp Web. You have to turn your camera around so that image of the QR code (in your phone's screen) is being **SCANNED FROM TOP TO BOTTOM**.

I had to look at it very carefully, and I think I ended holding my phone sideways! It was a bit confusing, and took me quite a few goes, it eventually worked. I was connected to WhatsApp Web! (And I haven't had to scan it again. I bookmarked the webpage, and whenever I go there I can Whatsapp on my pc)

Answer (score 0):

I just hit Print screen, pasted the screen image into Paint, and turned the image 90 degrees clockwise. Then Whatsapp scanned it correctly, in the first go itself. 
Phone: Samsung Galaxy Y

Answer (score -1):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Right arrow</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: And how to press Ctrl-Alt-Arrow on a touchscreen?

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution for me, I used the app Set Orientation, I used the Portrait mode and I managed to capture correctly the QR Code, the image is not too distorted. Good luck mate