# How to tweak camera/screen for Whatsapp web QR scanner

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, camera, qr-code

This is **NOT** a duplicate of [Why I can't scan the WhatsApp QR?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96546/why-i-cant-scan-the-whatsapp-qr) or [Can't scan QR code for WhatsApp web due to camera inverted or tilted on Galaxy Y Duos](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100434/cant-scan-qr-code-for-whatsapp-web-due-to-camera-inverted-or-tilted-on-galaxy-y).

- I'm using CyanogenMod 11 (snapshot M12) on HTC One X
- I have the latest WhatsApp 2.12.250

I'm trying to scan the WhatsApp web QR code on my computer. On my Android Whatsapp, I'm able to get to the point where the scanner is active, and the green scan bar goes up and down, but it never manages to capture the QR code on my computer screen.

I tried to scan the same code using the ZXing Barcode Scanner, and it only works when I turn on "Use auto focus", "No continuous focus", "No exposure".

The camera lense on my HTC One X is slightly scratched up, and the camera pictures has long been foggy. I suspect that the combination of my crappy camera and the computer LCD screen is preventing me from scanning the QR code.

So, since I can't change the camera setting in the Whatsapp QR scanner, is there any tip on how I can maximize the scannability of this web QR code?

Answer (score 2):

first of all, make sure you have a high speed internet connection.
If so then do -

- hold still your phone in landscape mode and try to scan for atleast 10 sec..
  (worked for my galaxy-y duos)

Comment: I have an LCD screen, too, that's why I'm here .... and this actually worked! Great trick.

Answer (score 0):

for crapy phones, i just cut the QR code a paste in paint, zoom in and capture perfectly

Comment: I had the same problem with an old Lenovo phone with a very crappy camera. I had to take a screenshot of the QR code, then I put it in GIMP editor and zoomed in to about 200%. That was enough for me to successfully scan it.

Comment: If that works, why doesn't zooming the image in the browser with Ctrl-+? Were you using an LCD display?

Answer (score -1):

I had issues with this due to my wide angle screen. If I moved the QR code to my 4:3 screen all of a sudden the scan would work normally. So, perhaps you can either change the resolution of your screen to one that is of a different ratio or take a screen shot of your QR code and then stretch it slightly (not just resize) to change it's height to width ratio until the WhatsApp scanner manages to read it.